# php strtotime() proper format

Tags: php, strtotime

How do I covert this to a proper timestamp?

```
$Year    = "2011";
$Day     = "7";
$Month   = "3";
$Hour    = "3";
$Minutes = "0";
$Seconds = "0";

/// How do I convert to right timestamp?
$dateToTimestamp =  strtotime("$Month $Day $Year $Hour $Minutes $Seconds");

echo "$dateToTimestamp"; // NOT WORKING. Seconds are updating each refresh. 
// They should be static from the var above.
```

Comment: Why not use `mktime()`, it takes all the values as separate arguments.

Comment: Humm, I will look into it. brb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mktime`

```
$dateToTimestamp = mktime($Hour, $Minutes, $Seconds, $Month, $Day, $Year);
```

Comment: That did it. Is there an easy way to convert the value timestamp number back to a "Month Day Year etc... " to test and debug?

Comment: `getdate()` returns an associative array with all the fields.

Comment: Is it so hard for you to look at the chapter of the PHP documentation on Date/Time functions?

Comment: I try but somtimes its hard for me to find these answers. Not sure why. Nevertheless, thank you so much. This helped a ton!!!